# SSRS - Date parameter - Previous month specific date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am Looking for a previous month specific date.
i.e. when the report is run on 25th of current month, the start date should **always** be previous month 25th.

Comment: Look at DATEADD and subtract a month from your current date. You might need to take into account where previous month has less days so if you run on 31st March, what date do you want to get data for.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337194(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Alan, that's what i am struggling with. i.e. when we have 31 days in the previous month, then i cannot just subtract 5 days or 6 days from previous month.
When the report is ran on 25th of a month, I always want the report to pull data from previous month 25 to current month 24th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for start date can simply be..

```
=DATEADD("m", -1, now())
```

If the run date is 25th October the start date will be 25th September.
If the run date is 31st March, the start date will be 28th of February, which is as close as you can reasonably get.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this.

Answer: =dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),25))

The above expression always looks for previous month 25th date, regardless when we run the report. for example if you always want to run on 11th of previous month then change the 25 to 11 on the above expression.

Comment: OK, well you question was badly worded then. It was not clear that it should run from the 25th no matter what date you ran it on, you example suggested that it must be the same day number but previous month.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same date of the previous month, just look for the previous month using DateAdd function like:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-1,Today())
```